# Is there a way to express any given natural number N as $N = \sum_{i=1}^ka_i^{p_i}$

Tags: summation, power-series, integers

Where every $a_i$ is the minimal and $p_i$ is maximal and $k$ (the number of terms) is the minimal, where $a_i$, $p_i$, $k$ are all natural numbers.

> Examples: 
> $10000 = 10^4$
> $164 = 10^2 + 2^6$

Number of terms are minimal

Base of each term is minimal

Power of each term is maximal

Hope this will be interesting )

Answer (score 0):

Certainly every number can be expressed as a sum of a whole bunch of $1^1$s. So the set of all such ways to express a given number is non-empty. It is also finite once you throw away all expressions that contain $1$ raised to a number greater than $1$. So there must be a minimal length. Then if there are multiple expressions of that same minimal length, there must be minimal bases. Then if there are multiple expressions of the same length with the same bases (if that's possible?), there must be maximal powers. That is, unless there is a $1^1$ somewhere in that expression. Then you obviously could make that exponent as large as you want.

The only thing really to explore is when you have two expressions $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^{p_i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^{p_{\sigma(i)}}$ for some permutation $\sigma$, i.e. you have the same bases and the same powers but mixed up, can these sums be equal? If not, then the expression found above is unique.

Comment: But the number of terms should be minimal, choosing 1 as base for each term will not guarantee this condition.

Comment: Choosing 1s just shows that the set of ways to represent the number is non-empty. Then when we look such ways, there must be a representation with minimal terms. It is almost certainly not the one with all 1s.

Answer (score 0):

If we choose all $a_i \in B = \{ b^0, b^1, \dots b^{k-1} \}$ , we get the base-$b$ representation of $N$. Every natural number has a unique base-$b$ representation. A restricted version of your problem statement is representing natural numbers in base-$b$ with the digits restricted to $\{ 0, 1 \}$.

Therefore, for a given base-$b$, you will have some integers that cannot be represented in the form you want. Those are the integers that have in their base-$b$ representation any digits in the set $B - \{ 0, 1 \}$.

So, given $N$ convert it to a base-$b$ representation. If it has any digits other than 0 or 1, it cannot be represented in that form. Where does that leave us?

You can also choose mixed radix representation. Even there, you are restricting digits to 0 or 1 and not all 0 in the representation you seek. So, there will be $N$ that cannot be represented for a given radix set.

However, for your question there is a straightforward answer from Lagrange's Four Square theorem. Every natural number can be represented as the sum of four squares. So, $p_i = p = 2, k = 4$ gives minimal $k$ for all $N$. Some $N$ can be represented with just two squares and some with just three. But all $N$ can be represented with four squares, so $k=4$ is minimal for all N.

Once we get the four square decomposition, you can check if any of those squares are perfect powers to ensure minimal $a_i$ and maximal $p_i$. There are multiple four square representations. So, if you want globally minimal $a_i$ and maximal_$p_i$, you need to search all four square representations and choose from them.

Finding all four square representations may be equivalent to factoring $N$, so may not be feasible for large $N$ (this is my guess, I could be wrong). However, if you are only looking for *any* such decomposition, [there are algorithms for getting them](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259152/efficient-method-to-write-number-as-a-sum-of-four-squares).